# C++ "Unhandled Exception" in implementation of custom exception handler

Tags: c++, exception

### EDIT: I figured it out

Well, I just discovered the error myself after spending more than four hours of frustration and bewilderment; and taking the time to elicit help here.... It suffices to say that I feel quite stupid at present.

Alas the issue was the following:

> I wanted my custom exception handler to catch the occurrence of a user
>   not entering a string or search character, however, it is perfectly
>   legal for a string or char to contain an empty space, newline
>   character, or null value. Therefore, the catch block would never
>   execute even though my validateInput method detected the erroneous
>   values and attempted to throw an exception (mind you the catch block
>   never executed, and thus an exception object never got created for the
>   throw to be accessed/allowed).
>
> What this amounts to is that there was never anything wrong with my
>   coding, I just simply needed to move the function call "result =
>   CountCharacter::count( stringIn, charIn );" into the try block such
>   that an exception could happen and the catch block run and create an
>   "CountCharacterException" object.
>
> Apologies to all, and thanks anyways.

Intro:
I am a tad leery of asking for help because I like to figure things out on my own, alas I stuck and have not been able to articulate a Google search that produces meaningful results. I am a college student and this is a C++ homework assignment that I have been working on, therefore, I am seeking an understanding of what I am doing wrong more so than simply a solution to make the problem go away.

Background:
The assignment is to explore the usage of recursion to search a user-entered string, for a user-entered search character, and output the results. Moreover, my instructor wanted us to incorporate exception handling into the assignment; and so far as I can tell the only means of an exception occurring during runtime is when either or both user-inputs are not provided. Definition and usage of a custom exception handler is not required. I chose to try and make my own just for the sake of learning something.

Additional Info:
I made my CountCharacter class static because it did not make sense to me to require that an object be created just to run the character count function and nothing more. I have tried to comment my code thoroughly such that my reasoning for various coding(s) is clear. Please bear in mind that I am a student, i.e. do not expect that my solution be the absolute best and/or that all functions be necessary according to programming best practices. Thank you in advance to anyone that helps me with this.

Error ( i.e. problem I cannot resolve):

> Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException:
>   External component has thrown an exception.    at
>   _CxxThrowException(Void* , *s*_ThrowInfo* )    at CountCharacter.count(basic_string\,std::alloc
>   ator >* s, SByte a) in
>   (Omitted file directory)countcharacter.h:line 14    at
>   main() in
>   (Omitted file directory)testcountcharacter.cpp:line 62    at
>   _mainCRTStartup()

Source Files:

### CounterCharacter.h

```
/* Filename:        CountCharacter.h
 * Last Modified:   26 February 2014
 * Author:          
 * Email:           
 * Course:          CIS354 - Algorithms and Data Structures
 * 
 * CountCharacter.h defines the static methods implemented in CountCharacter.cpp,
 * which, includes two fields for tracking found search characters (frequency) and
 * the current position of the search character (found), a recursive method count
 * that is overloaded to find said search character, and a method for validating that
 * that a user entered data (validateInput) that calls upon an exception handler
 */
#ifndef COUNTCHARACTER_H
#define COUNTCHARACTER_H
#include "CountCharacterException.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class CountCharacter
{
public:
    static int count(const string& s, char a);
private:
    static int frequency; // Track number of search character occurances
    static int found; // Store current position of character search matches
    static bool valid; // Stores whether a match was found
    static bool validateInput(const string& s, char a); // Determine if required inputs are present
    static int count(const string& s, char a, int pos); // Recursive helper function
}; // end CountCharacter Class

#endif
```

### CountCharacter.cpp

```
/* Filename:        CountCharacter.cpp
 * Last Modified:   26 February 2014
 * Author:          
 * Email:           
 * Course:          CIS354 - Algorithms and Data Structures
 * 
 * CountCharacter.cpp is the implementation of CountCharacter.h
 */
#include "CountCharacter.h"

    int CountCharacter::frequency = 0;
    int CountCharacter::found = 0;
    bool CountCharacter::valid = false;

int CountCharacter::count(const string& s, char a)
{
    if( !validateInput( s, a ) )
        throw CountCharacterException( s, a );
    else
        count( s, a, 0 );
    return frequency;
} // end recursive count function

int CountCharacter::count(const string& s, char a, int pos)
{
    found = s.find_first_of( a, pos );

    if(found != std::string::npos)
    {
        frequency++;
        count( s, a , found + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return frequency;
    }
} // end count helper function

bool CountCharacter::validateInput(const string& s, char a)
{
    if( (!s.empty()) && (a != '\0') && (a != '\n'))
    {
        valid = true;
    }

    return valid;
} // end validateInput() method
```

### TestCountCharacter.cpp

```
/* Filename:        TestCountCharacter.cpp
 * Last Modified:   26 February 2014
 * Author:          
 * Email:           
 * Course:          CIS354 - Algorithms and Data Structures
 * 
 * TestCountCharacter.cpp is a test-harness programm for CountCharacter.h. It prints a
 * header from SignatureBlock.h, and two brief prompts to allow a user to 
 * test implementation of the character counting functionality provided by
 * CountCharacter.h
 */
#include "CountCharacter.h"
#include "SignatureBlock.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string stringIn; // User-entered string
    char charIn; // User-entered search character
    int result; // Stores whether character match was found

    SignatureBlock::printHeader(); // Print Signature Block

        // Get a string and search character from user
        try
        {
            cout << "\nEnter a string: ";
            getline( cin, stringIn );

            cout << "\nEnter a character: ";
            // Using getchar() instead of "cin >> charIn", to allow for user to NOT enter a search
            // character, and thus allow exception handling to be tested
            charIn = getchar();
            // Discard any remaining characters in the input stream. NOTE: this will be relevant
            // once the exception handling is properly working, and I place the try...catch block
            // in a do...while loop to continue prompting until valid input is received
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        }
        catch( CountCharacterException& inputException)
        {
            cout << inputException.what();
            cout << "A search string, and a character to search for, must be entered.\n"
                 << "You entered String: \"" << inputException.getStringIn() << "\" and Character: \"" << inputException.getCharIn() << "\".\n" << endl;
        }

    // Call static method count with user-entered string and search character
    result = CountCharacter::count( stringIn, charIn );

    // If a character match was found
    if( result > 0 )
        cout << "\nCharacter \"" << charIn << "\" was found (" << result << ") times.\n" << endl;
    // No character match was found
    else 
        cout << "\nCharacter \"" << charIn << "\" was not found.\n" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### CountCharacterException.h

```
/* Filename:        CountCharacterException.h
 * Last Modified:   26 February 2014
 * Author:          
 * Email:           
 * Course:          CIS354 - Algorithms and Data Structures
 * 
 * CountCharacterException.h is a custom inline exception class for CountCharacter.h
 * that extends the standard invalid_argument class to make use of the what()
 * function in the exception class. It receives inputs of the user-entered
 * string and search character, as well as functions to return said fields; and throws
 * an error message as defined in the base classe's constructor (line 23)
 */
#ifndef COUNTCHARACTEREXCEPTION_H
#define COUNTCHARACTEREXCEPTION_H
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class CountCharacterException : public invalid_argument
{
public:
    CountCharacterException( const string& stringIn, char charIn) : invalid_argument("Invalid Input: ")
    {
        this->stringIn = stringIn;
        this->charIn = charIn;
    }
// Accessor method for user-entered search string
string getStringIn() const
{
    return stringIn;
} // end getString() method

// Accessor method for user-entered search character
char getCharIn() const
{
    return charIn;
} // end getCharIn() method
private:
    string stringIn;
    char charIn;
}; // end CountCharacterException class

#endif
```

Comment: `catch( const CountCharacterException& inputException)`